# NiFi PutDruidRecord not ingesting into Druid

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-nifi, druid

I am trying to ingest a csv into druid using GetFile and PutDruidRecord processors in NiFi but it is failing for some reason.

[image: Nifi Flow]

---

**Controller Services**

[image: Controller Services]

---

**CSVReader**

[image: CSVReader 1]

[image: CSVReader 2]

---

**CSVRecordSetWriter**

[image: CSVRecordSetWriter 1]

[image: CSVRecordSetWriter 2]

---

**DruidTranquilityController**

[image: DruidTranquilityController 1]

[image: DruidTranquilityController 2]

EDIT : I must confess that I'm not sure how to correctly configure CSVReader and CSVRecordSetWriter

Am I missing anything out such as passing in a json ingestion spec?

Comment: Please show the contents of the bulletins (the red icon on your `PutDruidRecord` processor) and the stacktraces in your `$NIFI_HOME/logs/nifi-app.log` file.

Comment: @Andy I have attached the log file and also added pictures of my config for CSVReader and CSVRecordSetWriter. As for the red icon, it was something to do with schema name in the CSV services

Comment: I also noticed that the flowfiles get dropped, not fail

Comment: You need to show the error from nifi-app.log that corresponds with the red bulletin on the processor, currently the section of nifi-app.log shown above has no errors in it

Comment: @BryanBende I have removed the log as there are no errors after I have made a few changes to the services (see pictures) but it keeps dropping for some reason. Based on my configuration, am I missing anything?

Comment: The description of when something goes to dropped is "// This happens when event timestamp targets a Druid Indexing task that has closed (Late Arriving Data)"